# How to return objects that have matching value when comparing to a separate array

Tags: reactjs

In my state I have an object called foodLog which holds all entries a user enters with one of the keys being `foodSelectedKey` and I'm trying to return all entries that have a matching value from that key with a different array called `foodFilter`.

However, this doesn't work and errors out saying `foodLog.filter()` isn't a function - I've looked this up and it's because it's an Object (I think). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    state = {
        // log food is for the logged entries
        foodLog: {},

        // used for when filtering food entries
        foodFilter: [],
    };


    findMatches = () => {
        let foodLog = this.state.foodLog;
        let foodFilter = this.state.foodFilter;
        let matched = foodLog.filter((item) => {
            return foodLog.foodsSelectedKey.map((food) => {
                return foodFilter.includes(food);
            });
        });
    };
```

Comment: `foodLog` is not an array. should it be?

Comment: You will have to provide some example input data and show what the expected output should be.

Comment: @GiorgiGvimradze I made it an object because to improve look up time, however, I'm not sure if this is the best move

Comment: @Candace The answer is ready, let me know if I can improve it

Answer (score 3):

I guess the reason behind the error `Is not a function` is that the object can not be looped. By that it means you can not iterate an object with differend variables inside, if it has no index to be iterated like an array. The same goes for `map()`, `find()` and similar functions which MUST be run with arrays - not objects.
As far as I understand you have an object named `foodLog` which has an array named `foodsSelectedKey`. We need to find intersected elements out of `foodFilter` with the array. This is what I came up with:

```js
  state = {
    // log food is for the logged entries
    foodLog: {
      foodsSelectedKey: [
        { id: 1, name: "chicken" },
        { id: 2, name: "mashroom" }
      ]
    },

    // used for when filtering food entries
    foodFilter: [
      { id: 1, name: "chicken" },
      { id: 2, name: "orange" }
    ]
  };

  findMatches = () => {
    let foodLog = this.state.foodLog;
    let foodFilter = this.state.foodFilter;
    let matched = foodLog.foodsSelectedKey.filter((key) =>
      {
        for (let i=0; i<foodFilter.length;i++){
          if(foodFilter[i].name===key.name)
            return true
        }
        return false;
      }
    );

    return matched;
  };
```

The Output is filtered array, in this case, of one element only:

```
[{
  id: 1
  name: "chicken"
}]
```

In order to check the output - run `console.log(findMatches())`. Here is the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-wilbur-6cjjb?file=/src/App.js) of the solution. (check console at right bottom)

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to this where I mapped with (key, index) and it was a solution similar to yours. Happy to share if interested. Thank you!